# How to find and list element which comes under a tag of ul li and ul li comes under div in selenium using java?

Tags: java, list, selenium, element

Website: https://stores.lenskart.com/
In this website I want to list store name its address and mobile no

Below is my code which i tried.

```
public class fetchdata {

public void fetchbengaluru() {
    suites.setupEnviroment();
    WebDriver driver = suites.getWebDriver();
    List<WebElement> div1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='border-manage store-info-box']"));
    System.out.println("No. of Stores: " + div1.size());

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < div1.size(); i++) {
            String storename = div1.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='store_name']")).getText();
            System.out.println("Store Name" + storename);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

In above code i am getting total no of store as 20 but not able to list their names and mobile no.
Element not found message is displayed 
As per my understanding i am not able to locate the element because its coming under ul-li and a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, we need to select Xpath in correct fashion to populate the data.

```
driver.get("https://stores.lenskart.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElementById("OutletSearch").sendKeys("Chennai", Keys.ENTER);

List<WebElement> storedetails = driver.findElementsByXPath("//a[@title='Lenskart.com']/b");

int storecount = storedetails.size();
        System.out.println(storecount);


for(int i=1;i<=storecount;i++) {

            String storename = driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@class='border-manage store-info-box']["+i+"]/ul//b").getText();

            String storephonenumber = driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@class='border-manage store-info-box']["+i+"]/ul/li[6]").getText();

            System.out.println(storename + " : "+storephonenumber.substring(0, 13));
        }
```

Output will be as follows

Lenskart.com at Purasawalkam : +91******

Lenskart.com at Nungambakkam : +91******

Lenskart.com at Tondiarpet : +91******

Lenskart.com at Royapuram : +91******

Lenskart.com at Mylapore : +91******

Comment: Sir, in this case you have filtered data by adding chennai in searchbox but whenever i try same code without searching anythings then org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document. This error is displayed

Comment: I ran the code, without entering  chennai .Below are the steps i followed. and it is working as expected.                                                                              Step1:  Open the site.                                                                                     Step2: get the list of the search list which is getting displayed by default.

Comment: Yes code is working perfectly but i am running code in eclipse sometimes it was happening that if i am running the code repeatedly it was throwing stale element exception. so for that i found one solution i refreshed project then it started working properly

Comment: Can i ask you for one more help? I want to write the above output in libreoffice sheet using selenium code. Can you please help me that

Comment: For writing and reading in Excel, please take a look on the below link :    
   http://learn-automation.com/read-and-write-excel-files-in-selenium/                                I am not sure about libreoffice is supported by selenium.

Comment: Yes i have visited that site i thought there might me solution for libreoffice. Ok fine ill try it in windows then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply store it in list and print the elements one by one with the help of for loop.**

## **I am getting the "total" as total=address.size() only once as it will be same for all the 3 elements and then printing all the value.**

`package newproj;`
`import java.util.List;`
`import org.openqa.selenium.By;`
`import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;`
`import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;`
`import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;`

`public class Lenskart {`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String url="https://stores.lenskart.com";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    List<WebElement> name=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='store_name redirectHome']"));

    List<WebElement> address=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='store_address redirectHome']"));

    List<WebElement> phone=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='store_phone']"));

    int total=address.size();
    for(int i=0;i<total;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("New address="+i);
        System.out.println(name.get(i).getText());
        System.out.println(address.get(i).getText());
        System.out.println(phone.get(i).getText());
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    driver.close();
}
```

## `}`

Output will be in this pattern.

New address=0
Lenskart.com at Science City Road, Sola
Shop No 01, Ground Floor, Royal Square
Science City Road, Sola
Ahmedabad - 380060
+917428891186
CALL

New address=1
Lenskart.com at Gurukul Road, Memnagar
Shop No 1, Shilp Complex
Gurukul Road, Memnagar
Ahmedabad - 380052
+917428891192
CALL

....

> and so on.

## .

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes its working but its not fetching all details of 20 stores on that page. I am getting output up to 6 stores.

Comment: Could you please scroll and count the stores in the page and recheck and also paste your code here as I ran it multiple times and it is showing all the 10 stores that are listed here.

Comment: Also please share the location so I will put the location and check if 20 stores are appearing and try to resolve the problem if any.

Comment: I am not filtering the data by default all stores are listed and there 20 stores on each page.

Comment: Please paste your code here . I will surely try to resolve as I am getting the list of all the 10 stores  which is loading by default by this code only.

Comment: I have copied your same code and not changed a single thing, also i tried copying my code here but its not allowing me to do so